# continuity of a function and net convergence

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory

The following is a statement and its proof in the Banach Algebra Techniques for Operator Theory by Douglas:

[image]

I don't understand the last part of the proof. In order to show that $f$ is continuous, one needs to show that
$$
f(y_\alpha)\to f(y).
$$
But what the proof gives is only the convergence of the subnet $(f_{\alpha_\beta})$:
$$
f(y_{\alpha_\beta})=g(x_{\alpha_\beta})\to f(y).
$$

Would anyone clarify how the continuity of $f$ is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $\langle f(y_\alpha):\alpha\in A\rangle$ does not converge to $f(y)$. Then there is a subnet $\langle y_{\alpha_\beta}:\beta\in B\rangle$ of $\langle y_\alpha:\alpha\in A\rangle$ such that $\{f(y_{\alpha_\beta}):\beta\in B\}$ is bounded away from $f(y)$. Now apply the argument given in the book to the net $\langle y_{\alpha_\beta}:\beta\in B\rangle$: it has a subnet whose image under $f$ converges to $f(y)$, which is absurd. Thus, $\langle f(y_\alpha):\alpha\in A\rangle\to f(y)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So accordingly, one can conclude that if $g:X\to Y$ is a map between two topological spaces and $x\in X$, then $g$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if $\langle g(x_\alpha)\rangle$ has a subnet converging to $g(x)$ for every net $x_\alpha\to x$?

Comment: @Jack: There’s a lot more going on here. In particular, the argument here relies on the compactness of $X$ and the relationship between $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Ah, I see. So in general, one only has $g:X\to Y$ is continuous at $x\in X$ if and only if $\langle g(x_\alpha)\rangle$ converges to $g(x)$ for every net $x_\alpha\to x$.

Comment: @Jack: That’s right. This is very much a special case. (And the author could certainly have done a better job of explaining it!)